# How to add "Merge branch 'name_of_branch' into 'name_of_branch'" in commit messages?

Tags: git, android-studio

All the time until today I git was adding me the commit message `Merge branch 'name_of_branch' into 'name_of_branch'`. It was also adding a list of conflicts which was super cool. But now when I merged a branch with conflicts the message is not there anymore.

How to re-enable it?

I want to do more-less opposite to what is asked here [How to avoid "Merge branch 'name_of_branch' in commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594894/how-to-avoid-merge-branch-name-of-branch-in-commit-messages).

Comment: Just to be clear, if you do a merge that doesn't have conflicts and thus git automatically commits with that commit message, but if you do a merge with conflicts and do a `git commit`, up pops your editor with the template message that only contains comments, and you want it to suggest the same template for you automatically? Did I get that right?

Comment: Since you specifically mention the list of conflicts, I would point this out:  The conflict list is commented out in the commit message editor, so by default *is not* included in the actual commit message.  So if you're wondering why the conflicts aren't making it into the log... the only way they ever would is if you uncommented them during the commit

Answer (score 0):

*Any* `git merge` sets up a default log message for the ultimate commit.  The "default default", i.e., what you get if you don't override the built-in default with your own default or with something explicit, includes both<sup>1</sup> the branch names, except when merging into `master` when it includes only the one non-`master` branch name.

The actual message itself, however, depends on several items (one of which I already mentioned):

- Did you run `git merge` yourself, or let `git pull` run it for you?
- Did you use the `--squash` option?
- Are you merging using a remote-tracking branch name?
- Is the current branch named `master`?
- Did you use the `--log` option, or configure `merge.log` to an integer value or to `true`?
- Did you set `merge.branchdesc` in your configuration?

See also [the `git fmt-merge-msg` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fmt-merge-msg.html) as well as [the `git merge` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

If you interactively edit the merge message—this is the default—you have a chance to modify it to your taste.  Your `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit-msg` hooks also have a chance to modify the message; see [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).  The [`git interpret-trailers` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-interpret-trailers.html) may also be useful in a commit message hook (see the example in the documentation).

---

<sup>1</sup>"All", for an octopus merge; but most merges just have two branch names involved.  And of course, when using raw commit hashes, there are no branch names available.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022): the default merge message prepared by "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb14cfdfd74c37f4319405eaebce0691c5b51db0/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> records the name of the current branch; the name can now be overridden with a new option to allow users to pretend a merge is made on a different branch.

See [commit bd2bc94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd2bc94252a47443e19d366f8cc9626d4f92df7a) (20 Dec 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bb14cfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb14cfdfd74c37f4319405eaebce0691c5b51db0), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd2bc94252a47443e19d366f8cc9626d4f92df7a): allow to pretend a merge is made into a different branch

> When a series of patches for a `topic-B` depends on having `topic-A`, the workflow to prepare the `topic-B` branch would look like this:
>
> ```
>     $ git checkout -b topic-B main
>     $ git merge --no-ff --no-edit topic-A
>     $ git am <mbox-for-topic-B
> ```
>
> When `topic-A` gets updated, recreating the first merge and rebasing the rest of the `topic-B`, all on detached HEAD, is a useful technique.
> After updating `topic-A` with its new round of patches:
>
> ```
> (0) $ git checkout topic-B
> (1) $ prev=$(git rev-parse 'HEAD^{/^Merge branch .topic-A. into}')
> (2) $ git checkout --detach $prev^1
> (3) $ git merge --no-ff --no-edit topic-A
> (4) $ git rebase --onto HEAD $prev @{-1}^0
> (5) $ git checkout -B @{-1}
> ```
>
> This will:
>
> - (0) check out the current `topic-B`.
> - (1) find the previous merge of `topic-A` into `topic-B`.
> - (2) detach the HEAD to the parent of the previous merge.
> - (3) merge the updated `topic-A` to it.
> - (4) reapply the patches to rebuild the rest of `topic-B`.
> - (5) update `topic-B` with the result.
>
> without contaminating the reflog of `topic-B` too much.
>
> `topic-B@{1}` is the "logically previous" state before `topic-A` got updated, for example.
> At (4), comparison (e.g. `range-diff`) between `HEAD` and `@{-1}` is a meaningful way to sanity check the result, and the same can be done at (5) by comparing `topic-B` and `topic-B@{1}`.
>
> But there is one glitch.
>
> The merge into the detached HEAD done in the step (3) above gives us "`Merge branch 'topic-A' into HEAD`", and does not say "`into topic-B`".
>
> Teach the "`--into-name=<branch>`" option to "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd2bc94252a47443e19d366f8cc9626d4f92df7a/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> and its underlying git fmt-merge-message, to pretend as if we were merging into `<branch>`, no matter what branch we are actually merging into, when they prepare the merge message.

`git fmt-merge-msg` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd2bc94252a47443e19d366f8cc9626d4f92df7a/Documentation/git-fmt-merge-msg.txt#L47-L50):

> 'git fmt-merge-msg' [-m ] [--into-name ] [--log[=] | --no-log]
>
> ### `--into-name <branch>`
>
> Prepare the merge message as if merging to the branch `<branch>`,
> instead of the name of the real branch to which the merge is made.

`git merge` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd2bc94252a47443e19d366f8cc9626d4f92df7a/Documentation/git-merge.txt#L80-L84):

> ### `--into-name <branch>`
>
> Prepare the default merge message as if merging to the branch
> `<branch>`, instead of the name of the real branch to which
> the merge is made.